# Google Dialogflow: How do i know which topics, use cases are allowed and which are not?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Obviously, one can't abuse keywords, but this is clear enough. Though, it's not clear whether or not i can use Dialogflow for, say, my name as invocation phrase? Like "ask Rick to introduce himself" - how do i know if this is allowed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, "Rick" is not just part of an invocation phrase - it is the name of the Action. So this goes beyond having it as a Dialogflow invocation - it goes to the invocation system for the Assistant.

While Google doesn't release the exact rules for naming, there are a few that are fairly clear:

1. Unless you have rights to an existing brand that is one word (see point 3), your name has to be at least two words long.
2. Some words don't count or aren't allowed. "My" is usually allowed in a name, but doesn't count towards the two word minimum. "Assistant" and "personal" usually aren't allowed since they're true for many Actions. You can bet that "my personal assistant" isn't considered very useful.
3. If you're trying to use well-known brands, you need to prove you have rights to use that brand. This isn't needed for every trademarked brand, and it isn't clear which ones Google requires it for, but if you need to use it you can [connect a website](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/connecting-properties) to prove you have the rights to use it.
4. Overly broad or generic names or phrases aren't allowed. (For example, "Santa Claus" wouldn't be allowed because it would be used by a lot of actions, while "my local government" would probably be rejected because it is a generic term.) (Many of these will likely turn into the "built-in intents" that you'll be able to use, but there is no guarantee and the details of this aren't fully clear yet.)

In your example, there are a lot of "Rick"s around, and it is a single word, so it is likely that this would be rejected. If you controlled rick.com, however, it is possible that it would be allowed as a connected property.

Comment: thanks! could you add url to the terms that you was referring to in your answer?

Comment: I used "term" in the sense of phrases. Hopefully I clarified that. As I said, these rules don't seem to be published in one place by Google, so there is no link to them, but some of the info is available through their design guide and the link I was able to provide.